# How to avoid putting the whole table into memory when JOIN in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a simple query that joins data from two tables:

```sql
SELECT match_id, user_id FROM match_users JOIN matches USING match_id WHERE match_id = 321
```

At the end I want to get the following data (considering that `start_time` is a column in `matches` table):

| match_id | user_id | start_time | another columns in matches table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 321 | 17414 | 2000 | ... |
| 321 | 100394 | 2000 | ... |
| 321 | 134 | 2000 | ... |

For such a simple query, ClickHouse puts the table (~230GB) into memory. Currently I'm using trick that works for a rows with the same `match_users.match_id`:

```js
// ...
let match = await this.ch.findOne('SELECT * FROM matches WHERE match_id = 321 LIMIT 1');
let match_users = await this.ch.find('SELECT * FROM match_users WHERE match_id = 321');
// ...
```

But in case like below:

```js
let player_matches = await this.ch.find('SELECT * FROM match_users WHERE user_id = 1');
for (let player_match of player_matches) {
    let match = await this.ch.findOne(`SELECT * FROM matches WHERE match_id = ${player_match.match_id} LIMIT 1`);
    // ...
}
```

it works too slow.

Is it possible to make ClickHouse avoid loading the whole table into memory to join 4 rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sub-queries

```sql
SELECT t1.match_id, t1.user_id FROM 
 (SELECT match_id, user_id FROM match_users WHERE match_id = 321) t1
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT match_id FROM matches WHERE match_id = 321) t2
ON t1.match_id=t2.match_id
```

Comment: I would add that given filter on match_id in each subquery, ON condition can be removed (all values are same anyway) -  if this is really the query original author wants, it can be plain cross join without condition.

Comment: Unfortunately, not for my case. This can work in the case where we have the exact match_id. But I need to be able to select without having the exact match_id.

Comment: Typical JOIN in clickhouse loads the right side (the table `matches`) to memory in order to perform the operation - this is the reason why using a subquery will reduce resource consumption and runs faster.